# How to grab specific element to value

Tags: regex, vb.net

I've this string value:

```
<a href="/players/pablo-daniel-osvaldo/17826/" class="flag_16 left_16 italy_16_left">P. Osvaldo</a>
```

I want to delete all and take only P. Osvaldo; This is just a sample value, P. Osvaldo is not always the same, then I would find a general algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `(?<=>)[^>]*(?=</a>$)` to extract all text inside the `a` element.

[regex101 demo.](https://regex101.com/r/hH4dE3/3)

Comment: you can do it directly on the line of code where I capture the value from the web, for example: = .Giocatore Regex.Match (Content, "<td class =" "large player-link" "\ s *> (. +?) </td>").Groups(1).ToString???

Comment: His sample is small, but this won't work for something like: <a href="http://" title="a>a"> Some text </a>

Comment: How to apply this code to variable? Can you show an example?

Comment: @EspertoDiProgrammazione: I don't know VB.NET, but according to a 2-minute google search this should work: `Regex.Match(my_variable, "(?<=>)[^>]*(?=</a>$)").Value`.